# Openshift - create job on file change

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I would like to start a pod/cronjob only after a specific file is created on a NAS that has been mounted as PVC (PersistentVolumeClaim).

Is there a way to "watch" a folder and only trigger the pod creation after we're sure that the file is there?

We would like to create the pod at the latest possible moment in order not to reserve computing power from the cluster on pods that are "waiting" for something to happen.

Also, we can't use Openshift pipeline (aka Tekton) or other operator that require cluseter-wide permissions because of company policies.

Comment: Kubernetes doesn't have a concept of "file" at all.  A custom controller could do this, using the Kubernetes API to create the Job.

Comment: Care to expand it into an answer? Maybe with some example on how to build a simple custom controller to check the files in a PersistentVolumeClaim. I have added a bounty :)

Comment: Alternatively, why not add a tiny initContainer that waits for the file(s) to be created?

Comment: @Botje Thats a great idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider a custom solution that utilizes a small, lightweight *watcher* container.
That container would monitor the specified directory for the file creation event, and then trigger the desired job.

```bash
+------------------+      +-----------------+      +-------------------+
|                  |      |                 |      |                   |
|  Watcher Pod     |----->|  NAS (PVC)      |      |  Triggered Pod    |
|  (Custom Image)  |      |  (File Check)   |      |  (Task Execution) |
|                  |      |                 |      |                   |
+------------------+      +-----------------+      +-------------------+
```

Create a Docker image that includes a script to watch the specified directory on the NAS (mounted as a [PersistentVolumeClaim (PVC)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/)). That script `watcher.sh` can use tools like [`inotifywait`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) (for Linux environments) to monitor for file creation events.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

WATCHED_DIR="/path/to/watched/directory"
FILE_NAME="trigger_file.txt"

echo "Watching for $FILE_NAME in $WATCHED_DIR"
while true; do
    inotifywait -e create "$WATCHED_DIR"
    if [ -f "$WATCHED_DIR/$FILE_NAME" ]; then
    echo "$FILE_NAME found, triggering the job..."
    # Trigger pod creation or cronjob here
    break
    fi
done
```

Add a Dockerfile for watcher:

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache inotify-tools bash
ADD watcher.sh /watcher.sh
RUN chmod +x /watcher.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/watcher.sh"]
```

Then deploy this image as a pod in [OpenShift](https://www.dynatrace.com/news/blog/what-is-openshift-2/), making sure the NAS is mounted as a PVC to the same path as specified in your script.

In the part of the script where it states `# Trigger pod creation or cronjob here`, you can use the [OpenShift CLI (`oc`)](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.11/cli_reference/openshift_cli/getting-started-cli.html) to trigger a pod or cronjob. However, this requires `oc` to be available in your image, and appropriate permissions set up for the service account used by the watcher pod to create jobs in OpenShift.

```bash
oc run my-job --image=myjobimage:latest --restart=Never
```

Or to create a cronjob, you could have a predefined cronjob definition and create it using:

```bash
oc create -f my-cronjob.yaml
```

---

> We cannot trigger jobs with OC from the container, I have to find another way to do so.

Then use Kubernetes resources that can *self-trigger* based on the creation of a file, without needing to call `oc` or `kubectl` from within a container.
Define a [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) that periodically checks for the presence of the file and proceeds with its task if the file exists. If the file is not found, the container can exit without performing any actions.

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: conditional-trigger-job
spec:
  schedule: "*/5 * * * *" # Runs every 5 minutes, adjust according to needs
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: check-and-run
            image: myjobimage:latest
            command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
            args:
            - >
              if [ -f /mnt/data/trigger_file.txt ]; then
                echo "File exists. Running job...";
                # Place job logic here
              else
                echo "File not found. Exiting...";
                exit 0;
              fi
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          volumes:
          - name: nas-volume
            persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: my-pvc
```

The pod's service account associated with the CronJob should have *minimal* permissions, only allowing it to perform necessary actions.
No need for `oc` or `kubectl` commands within the container.

---

This differs from [Botje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1548468/botje)'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77905314/openshift-create-job-on-file-change/77924238#comment137368616_77905314) which is designed to run to completion before the main containers in a Pod start.

Comment: Feels like a ChatGPT generated answer.. I mean, it isn't wrong but a rewrite could help.

Also we can't trigger jobs with OC from the container, I have to find another way to do so

Comment: @Owlzy "we can't trigger jobs with OC from the container": you could use a CronJob that periodically checks for the presence of the file and proceeds with its task if the file exists. That would not require `oc` commands from within containers. I will wait first for Botje's answer regarding an initContainer.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [argo events](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-events/) if that is allowed by your policies. File watcher is just a tiny fraction of [what it could do](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-events/concepts/event_source/).